# Variable in cakephp configuration setting

Tags: cakephp

There could be a vary simple way to achieve what I am trying to do in cakephp but I am unable.
here is what I am trying to do : 
I have a settings file which I read through configuration object and the setting as

```
$config['pageMeta']=array(
'1'=>array('desc'=>'<?php echo $param1 ?> some data, <?php echo $param2 ?> some content in <?php echo $param3 ?>')
);
```

What I would like to do is that read the above string as

`Configure::read('pageMeta.1.desc');` and somehow evaluate 'param1','param2' and 'param3' replaced with actual values.  I am doing this in view layout. I could probably write a function to do string replace but not sure if that is the right way to do.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks
aboxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"<?php echo $param1 ?>"` for the purpose of string replacement within a string is a bad idea. There are better ways to do it:

1. Cake's own [`String::insert`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1483/insert) function:

   ```
   $str = 'Hello :place, the :noun is :adjective.';
   echo String::replace($str, array('place' => 'World', 'noun' => 'weather', 'adjective' => 'hot'));
   // Hello World, the weather is hot.
   ```
2. PHP's [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf):

   ```
   $str = 'Hello %s, the %s is %s.';
   echo sprintf($str, 'World', 'weather', 'hot');
   // Hello World, the weather is hot.
   ```

Maybe you're also just looking for standard [localization](http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1228/Internationalization-Localization).

Comment: deceze,

thanks. was hoping to get some automagic with cakephp but your solutions are completely acceptable. I would stick with first solution. will report back if any issues